# Layered box annotations

Tags: chart.js

Is it possible to draw a box annotation on top of another one?
I need to have two bands, one higher than the other as shown below.

[image: chart]

I was able to achieve so by using three annotations with the code below. But, it would be better if I can just have two annotations (one with `yMin: 4, yMax: 14` and another with `yMin: 2, yMax: 18`)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.1.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-annotation@2.1.1/dist/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

    const inner = {
      type: 'box',
      borderWidth: 0,
      drawTime: 'beforeDraw',
      yMin: 4,
      yMax: 14,
      backgroundColor: '#bdc3c7'
    };

    const outerUpper = {
      type: 'box',
      borderWidth: 0,
      drawTime: 'beforeDraw',
      yMin: 2,
      yMax: 4,
      backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1'
    };

    const outerLower = {
      type: 'box',
      borderWidth: 0,
      drawTime: 'beforeDraw',
      yMin: 14,
      yMax: 18,
      backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1'
    };

    new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          annotation: {
            annotations: {
              inner,
              outerUpper,
              outerLower
            }
          }
        }
      },
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If anyone else has this issue, I found the answer I was looking for. https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/guide/types/line.html#positioning.

The `z` property determines the drawing stack level of the line annotation element. All visible elements will be drawn in ascending order of `z` option, with the same `drawTime` option.